# Complex structure on Cylinder $S^1\times I$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $C=S^1\times I$ be the cylinder where $S^1$ is the unit circle and $I=(0,1)$. How to make $C$ to be a Riemann surface? And how to prove this Riemann surface is conformal to some standard annulus $A=\{1<|z|<r\}$. Any hint and help will welcome!

Comment: That space is homeomorphic to an annulus... Use that.

Answer (score 2):

You have a conformal mapping from $(0,1) \times [0,2\pi i]$ to $A_{e}= \{ 1 < |z|< e\}$, $z \mapsto e^z$, that gives a conformal bijection between $(0,1) \times S^1$ and $A_e$.

Note that the conformal structure on $(0,1) \times S^1$ comes from the Riemannian structure on the cylinder as an imbedded surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$.